# edit sf point conditionally

Tags: r, sf

I have an sf point dataframe, with a single incorrect point. I know what it's coordinates should be, but I'm not sure how best to directly edit them. I'm aiming for a conditional edit like the following

```
new_point <- st_point(c(145.38626, -16.43350)) %>% 
               st_sfc(crs = 4283) %>% 
               st_transform(., 3577)

allpoints_clean <- allpoints %>%
  mutate(geometry = ifelse(s_id == '1', st_geometry(new_point), geometry)
```

but this produces the error 'no simple features geometry column present', which is definitely not the case. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: I think direct overwrite with assignment is best in this case. Explore allpoints$geometry[[1]] with str and unclass to get the idea. Sf was not designed with this kind of flexibility in mind, but it's light enough to diy in cases like this.

Comment: And just quietly, this is exactly why spbabel exists. I am happy to help find a solution but it might be best in another forum (like the spbabel issues on github)

Comment: huh. yeah ok `allpoints$geometry[allpoints$sid %in% 'id1'] <- new_point` works as an overwrite, but `allpoints[allpoints$sid %in% 'id1', allpoints$geometry] <- new_point` doesn't (because list-column??)

Comment: Run `ifelse(p$s_id == 1, st_geometry(new_point), p$geometry)` and you'll see the spatialness is dropped by `ifelse`. See my additional edit for tidyverse solution.

Comment: excellent, thanks - spatialness is dropped because the test in ifelse refers to a non-spatial object?

Comment: Yes, `ifelse` gets its returned class from the first argument. See ?ifelse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a reproducible example:

```
> p = st_sf(a=3, geometry = st_sfc(st_point(1:2)))
> p = rbind(p,p,p,p,p)
> p$s_id = c(0,0,1,0,0)
> p
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 2 xmax: 1 ymax: 2
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
  a   geometry s_id
1 3 POINT(1 2)    0
2 3 POINT(1 2)    0
3 3 POINT(1 2)    1
4 3 POINT(1 2)    0
5 3 POINT(1 2)    0
```

Then its just a conditional replacement into the `geometry` column:

```
> p$geometry[p$s_id==0]=new_point
> p
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 2 xmax: 1 ymax: 2
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
  a                       geometry s_id
1 3 POINT(1433173.30406075 -182...    0
2 3 POINT(1433173.30406075 -182...    0
3 3                     POINT(1 2)    1
4 3 POINT(1433173.30406075 -182...    0
5 3 POINT(1433173.30406075 -182...    0
```

Oops I've replaced `s_id==0` lines (demonstrating how you can replace multiple geometries). Replace with `s_id==1` for your use!

The problem in your example is the `ifelse` is returning a plain list. Wrap it in `st_sfc` and your mutate works..

```
> p = rbind(p,p,p,p,p)
> p$s_id=c(0,0,1,0,0)
> p
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 2 xmax: 1 ymax: 2
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
  a   geometry s_id
1 3 POINT(1 2)    0
2 3 POINT(1 2)    0
3 3 POINT(1 2)    1
4 3 POINT(1 2)    0
5 3 POINT(1 2)    0
> pm = p %>% mutate(geometry = st_sfc(ifelse(s_id == 1, st_geometry(new_point), geometry)))
> pm
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: -1824335 xmax: 1433173 ymax: 2
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
  a s_id                       geometry
1 3    0                     POINT(1 2)
2 3    0                     POINT(1 2)
3 3    1 POINT(1433173.30406075 -182...
4 3    0                     POINT(1 2)
5 3    0                     POINT(1 2)
```

Comment: yep that's it, see comment above - although there seems to be some issues around index-referencing df's with list-columns that I don't fully understand yet.